# crontab modification is not permanent

Tags: cron

I am a below avg linux users, so my question may be basic to most of you guys. 
When I use `crontab -e`, the changes I do do no last. If I add a line, it is not there the next day. Perhaps there is a process which manages the `crontab` file and rewrites it periodically.

How do I modify the crontab file so it will stick?

Comment: Do you actually save the file correctly? If you immediately run `crontab -e` again (don't wait till the next day) do you see your changes? If not, you can rule out anything resetting your crontab.

Comment: Is the system administered by you?

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the Linux distribution you use and the line(s) you added to the crontab ?

Comment: crontabs are not reset by default on any Unix system.  If you are seeing this on your system, then there is something odd going on. Could you describe what Unix you are using, and also if you see crontab entries that you have not put there yourself (this would indicate a compromised system).

Comment: Thank you guys for the responses. It made think a little more and figure out the issue. The system in stake is not a pure linux. It is a QNAP (nas) device. crontab -e does not work by definition, I need to edit /etc/config/crontab